# Reason behind more Reactivity of Unsaturated Hydrocarbons

Tags: organic-chemistry, bond, reactivity, hydrocarbons

My textbook says that **unsaturated hydrocarbons are more reactive than saturated ones**. But double and triple bonds are stronger than single bonds.
What is the explanation for this?

Comment: Double and triple bond have greater electron density that make them reactive to electrophiles

Comment: Double and triple bonds as a whole are stronger than single bonds, but the additional pi bonds are easier to break than a sigma bond.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unsaturated regions are electron-rich and typically allow for electrophilic attack, such as by halogens or protons. Saturated hydrocarbons usually react only with radicals (radical halogenation). C-H activation is often hard in saturated hydrocarbons.

While double and triple bonds are stronger than a single bond when looking at complete cleavage of a bond, one notices that the bond strength of a double bond is less than twice the bond strength of a single bond (with other factors being comparable, there are surely some exceptions). When a double bond reacts, it typically is changed into a single bond, not fully cleaved. Similar arguments hold for triple bonds.